# How to restore a locally lost git bare repo (using separate-git-dir) with one of its remotes

Tags: git, git-remote, git-bare

A long time ago, I set up a repo using git --separate-git-dir because I did want the repo inside the working directory. Unfortunately, that separate (presumably "bare"?) repo has been lost to hard drive failure, and I want to rebuild it using the contents of a remote I had added (which was pushed to frequently).

#### How do I do that?

I tried by recreating a new, empty git repo:

```
git init --separate-git-dir=/desired/path/to/bare/git/repo
```

This of course creates a `.git` file in the working directory with the contents, `gitdir: /desired/path/to/bare/git/repo`

Then, I did:

```
git remote add network ssh://host/path/to/repo
git fetch network
```

But, if I run `git status`, I get

```
On branch master

No commits yet
```

#### What I'd like to get

I only ever used (and pushed) the master branch. I am hoping to get this repo to a state WITHOUT MODIFYING THE WORKING DIRECTORY where I can type `git status` and hopefully it only sees the changes between the current, unmodified working directory and the last commit pushed to the remote, which should now be in my local bare?

I'm really just trying to pick up where I left off.

Thank you.

Comment: `fetch` does not add commits to the master. You'd better `pull` instead.

Comment: Not all that important to the problem, but a Git repository initialized with `--separate-git-dir` is *not* a bare repository, it's just one where the work-tree is at point A and the repository is at point B.

Comment: The main problem here is that the *index* is in the repository as well, so you've created a new, empty repository, then populated it with some commits (found by the name `network/master`), but you still have no `master` and the index of your new empty repository is still empty. You should be able to, at this point, run `git branch master network/master` to create the (local) branch name `master` pointing to the same commit as `network/master`. This will by default set the upstream for `master` to `network/master` too; add `--no-track` to prevent that if you don't want it, or [continued]

Comment: ... or unset it afterwards. Before or after that, fill in the index from this commit using `git read-tree` and any name or hash ID that represents this commit. For instance, `git read-tree master` after creating the name `master`, or `git read-tree network/master` at any time. After doing both of these you will have a local branch named `master` and a populated index, and `git status` will have three things to compare: a commit found via HEAD, a populated index—these two will match—and your existing work-tree.

Comment: @Serge, if I pulled, it would update the working directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: what remains is to create a `master` branch, probably with `git branch master network/master` (perhaps with various flags; see below), *and* fill in the index, probably using `git read-tree`.  Hence:

```
git branch master network/master
git read-tree master
```

is probably sufficient.

---

Let me turn my comments above into an actual answer now that I have a bit of time to spare.  We've noted that `--separate-git-dir` doesn't make the repository *bare*—a bare repository is one with *no* work-tree—it just puts the work-tree and repository (`.git/*` files) in two different locations in the file system.  To make this function, Git adds a `.git` *file* in the work-tree, containing the path name of the repository itself, as you noted.

So, in this case, that repository itself has been damaged or destroyed.  You have a work-tree with no repository.  You've created a new, empty repository using another `git init --separate-git-dir=...` and run the commands:

> ```
> git remote add network ssh://host/path/to/repo
> ```

(I would probably have named the remote `origin` rather than `network` but there's nothing *wrong* with `network`, it's just a bit unconventional.)

What you needed to do next is populate the repository itself with commits, and you did that:

> ```
> git fetch network
> ```

Your repository itself (in whichever directory) now has some set of commits, copied from the Git repository at the URL at which you ran `git fetch`.

At this point *almost* everything is normal.  Two things are missing:

- There are no local branches, in spite of the *current* branch being the one named `master`.  The branch `master` doesn't exist.
- The index—the collection of files that would go into the *next* commit you would make—is empty.

If you were to make a commit now, that would create a commit with no parent commit, and with no content (the [empty tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9765453/1256452)), and create the branch `master` in the process, but that's pretty clearly *not* what you want.  Instead, you probably want:

1. To create the local name `master` to match the remote-tracking name `origin/master` that points to the final commit of the branch `master` in the `network` repository from which you copied all its commits.  To do that, use:

   ```
   git branch master network/master
   ```

   You can use anything you like as the final argument, as long as it names any actual commit: a raw hash ID will suffice, or something like `network/master^`, or `network/master~3`, or whatever.  If you *do* use the name `network/master`, Git recognizes that this is a *remote-tracking name*.<sup>1</sup>  As a consequence, `git branch` sets this remote-tracking name as the *upstream* of the new (local) branch name `master`.

   More precisely, the automatic upstream setting is the *default* action for `git branch` here (and for some forms of `git checkout` as well).  You can configure Git to change the default, or you can add command line flags to override whatever default you have or have not set.

   To *prevent* this upstream-setting, use `git branch --no-track master network/master`.  To *force* the upstream-setting, use `git branch --track master network/master`, which you can abbreviate as `git branch --track network/master`.

   Whether and when to set the upstream setting is up to you.  You can always change it later using `git branch --set-upstream`, or remove it later using `git branch --unset-upstream`.
2. Now that `master` exists—or you can do this before creating `master`, but I'd do it afterward as it just feels simpler and easier to get right—you will want to populate your index from the commit you've selected as your current commit.  Normally—in a situation other than this "repair broken Git repository" case—we'd do steps 1 and 2 all together at once using `git checkout`, but you want to do this *without* disturbing the current work-tree, and `git checkout` disturbs the current work-tree.  So we do this as a separate step 2, using one of Git's lower level *plumbing* commands:<sup>2</sup>

   ```
   git read-tree master
   ```

   (or `git read-tree HEAD` or `git read-tree @` if you want to type less: all three do the same thing).  This simply reads the named commit into the index, without doing anything else at all: it replaces whatever was in the index (which was nothing) with whatever is in the named commit.

After doing the `git branch` and `git read-tree`, `git status` will be able to compare the current commit—the one named by `HEAD` / `master`—with the current index contents—they will match of course—and then compare the current index contents with the current work-tree contents.  These will match or differ based on which commit you chose when setting up your own `master` in step 1, and in any case you'll be ready to `git add` and make new commits if you like.

---

<sup>1</sup>A *remote-tracking name* is any name whose full spelling starts with `refs/remotes/`.  In this case `network/master` is really `refs/remotes/network/master`.  Git documentation mostly calls these *remote-tracking branch names* but the word "branch" here is, I think, more misleading than not, so I omit it.

These names exist in *your* Git repository and are automatically created and updated based on the branch names that your Git gets from the other Git—the one at the URL stored under the name `network`—whenever your Git does a `git fetch` from the Git at `network`.  A successful `git push network` also updates any branches that they set based on your Git's requests.

<sup>2</sup>The distinction between *plumbing* and *porcelain* in Git is really in terms of who is meant to use a command: a porcelain command is meant to be user-friendly and goal-oriented,<sup>3</sup> and a plumbing command is meant to be a command that a porcelain command might use as one of a series of such commands (and/or in combination with other system utilities) in order to accomplish some actual goal.  Thus, plumbing commands tend to be extra-specific and mechanism-oriented (`git read-tree`, "fill index from commit"; `git rev-parse`, "turn human-readable name into internal hash ID"; `git update-ref`, "write raw hash ID into arbitrary reference").

<sup>3</sup>Or perhaps "less actively user-hostile". :-) See also https://git-man-page-generator.lokaltog.net/

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the best way:

The commands you entered is a good start:

```
git init --separate-git-dir=/desired/path/to/bare/git/repo
git remote add network ssh://host/path/to/repo
git fetch network
```

Now, you have a new repository, and your work tree remains completely unchanged. Git creates a branch named "master" automatically.  The branch network/master contains all the commit history.  But your local master is an orphan..no commits on it.  The solution is to point your local master to the network master:

```
git reset network/master
```

Your local working tree remains unchanged...but your index and HEAD are now identical to network/master.  Git status and git diff should show your changed files.  You can now git commit -a or git commit add  and git commit.

Comment: Note that --separate-git-dir=/desired/path/to/bare/git/repo does not actually create a bare repository.  You are simply telling git to create the repository for your worktree somewhere other than the default location.

Comment: This looks great and along the lines of what I was thinking, but I already applied @torek's solution which worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) mentions in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58259804/6309):

> We've noted that `--separate-git-dir` doesn't make the repository bare—a bare repository is one with no work-tree — it just puts the work-tree and repository (`.git/*` files) in two different locations in the file system.

To be even clearer, you could not use `--bare` with  `--separate-git-dir` anyway, considering you want to get a working tree, that you then need to populate (`git switch -C master` should be enough)

With Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), the purpose of "[`git init --separate-git-dir`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a654836d96aced223bfbee57bd2ac1989eb6d77f/Documentation/git-init.txt#L62)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init.txt---separate-git-dirltgitdirgt))</sup>" is to initialize a new project with the repository separate from the working tree, or, in the case of an existing project, to move the repository (the `.git/` directory) out of the working tree.
It does not make sense to use `--separate-git-dir` with a bare repository for which there is no working tree, so disallow its use with bare repositories.

See [commit ccf236a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ccf236a23adb5cfb4e5285daad083149458d7828) (09 Aug 2020) by [Eric Sunshine (`sunshineco`)](https://github.com/sunshineco).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a654836](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a654836d96aced223bfbee57bd2ac1989eb6d77f), 24 Aug 2020)</sup>

> ### [`init`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ccf236a23adb5cfb4e5285daad083149458d7828): disallow `--separate-git-dir` with bare repository
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Eric Sunshine</sup>

> The purpose of "[`git init --separate-git-dir`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a654836d96aced223bfbee57bd2ac1989eb6d77f/Documentation/git-init.txt#L62)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#Documentation/git-init.txt---separate-git-dirltgitdirgt))</sup>" is to separate the repository from the worktree.
> This is true even when `--separate-git-dir` is used on an existing worktree, in which case, it moves the `.git/ subdirectory` to a new location outside the worktree.
>
> However, an outright bare repository (such as one created by "[`git init --bare`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ccf236a23adb5cfb4e5285daad083149458d7828/Documentation/git-init.txt#L47)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#Documentation/git-init.txt---bare))</sup>), has no worktree, so using `--separate-git-dir` to separate it from its non-existent worktree is nonsensical.
> Therefore, make it an error to use `--separate-git-dir` on a bare repository.
>
> Implementation note: "[`git init`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ccf236a23adb5cfb4e5285daad083149458d7828/Documentation/git-init.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init))</sup> considers a repository bare if told so explicitly via `--bare` or if it guesses it to be so based upon heuristics.
>
> - In the explicit `--bare` case, a conflict with `--separate-git-dir` is easy to detect early.
> - In the guessed case, however, the conflict can only be detected once "bareness" is guessed, which happens after "[`git init`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ccf236a23adb5cfb4e5285daad083149458d7828/Documentation/git-init.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init))</sup> has begun creating the repository.
>
> Technically, we can get by with a single late check which would cover both cases, however, erroring out early, when possible, without leaving detritus provides a better user experience.

---

With Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), "[`git worktree`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/eb7460fd312511941d64007b5dfc4799a20a8d18/Documentation/git-worktree.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree))</sup> gained a "`repair`" subcommand to help users recover after moving the worktrees or repository manually without telling Git.

Also, "[`git init --separate-work-dir=<path>`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/59d876ccd688ae0fe761b571afe77a7c8317eb88/Documentation/git-init.txt#L64)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#Documentation/git-init.txt---separate-git-dirltgitdirgt))</sup> no longer corrupts administrative data related to linked worktrees.

See [commit 59d876c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/59d876ccd688ae0fe761b571afe77a7c8317eb88), [commit 42264bc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/42264bc841d416aab5a980cb4eeedf687f1190a5), [commit b214ab5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b214ab5aa597e748c228e657d4eb7c18960e6a67), [commit bdd1f3e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bdd1f3e4da716012a52194cdfbc9c80dfdce87d4) (31 Aug 2020), and [commit e8e1ff2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e8e1ff24c5cf885c8d0ac208b58ccaf3760e8bfa) (27 Aug 2020) by [Eric Sunshine (`sunshineco`)](https://github.com/sunshineco).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit eb7460f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eb7460fd312511941d64007b5dfc4799a20a8d18), 09 Sep 2020)</sup>

> ### [`init`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/59d876ccd688ae0fe761b571afe77a7c8317eb88): make --separate-git-dir work from within linked worktree
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Henré Botha</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Eric Sunshine</sup>

> The intention of [`git init --separate-work-dir=<path>`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/59d876ccd688ae0fe761b571afe77a7c8317eb88/Documentation/git-init.txt#L64)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#Documentation/git-init.txt---separate-git-dirltgitdirgt))</sup> is to move the `.git/` directory to a location outside of the main worktree.
>
> When used within a linked worktree, however, rather than moving the `.git/` directory as intended, it instead incorrectly moves the worktree's `.git/worktrees/<id>` directory to `<path>`, thus disconnecting the linked worktree from its parent repository and breaking the worktree in the process since its local .
> [`git`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/59d876ccd688ae0fe761b571afe77a7c8317eb88/Documentation/git-.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-))</sup> file no longer points at a location at which it can find the object database.
> Fix this broken behavior.
>
> An intentional side-effect of this change is that it also closes a loophole not caught by [ccf236a23a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ccf236a23adb5cfb4e5285daad083149458d7828) ("`init`: disallow `--separate-git-dir` with bare repository", 2020-08-09, Git v2.29.0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a654836d96aced223bfbee57bd2ac1989eb6d77f)) in which the check to prevent `--separate-git-dir` being used in conjunction with a bare repository was unable to detect the invalid combination when invoked from within a linked worktree.
> Therefore, add a test to verify that this loophole is closed, as well.

---

With Git 2.31 (Q1 2021), "[`git worktree repair`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8664fcb83b8ea51d33f0ba4b1183eaf5c8b5c327/Documentation/git-worktree.txt#L130)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree#Documentation/git-worktree.txt-repairltpathgt...))</sup> learned to deal with the case where both the repository and the worktree moved.

See [commit cf76bae](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cf76baea41bb7f6431dbfa5744c861fdb844d20b) (21 Dec 2020) by [Eric Sunshine (`sunshineco`)](https://github.com/sunshineco).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8664fcb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8664fcb83b8ea51d33f0ba4b1183eaf5c8b5c327), 06 Jan 2021)</sup>

> ### [`worktree`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cf76baea41bb7f6431dbfa5744c861fdb844d20b): teach `repair` to fix multi-directional breakage
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Eric Sunshine</sup>

> [`git worktree repair`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/cf76baea41bb7f6431dbfa5744c861fdb844d20b/Documentation/git-worktree.txt#L130)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree#Documentation/git-worktree.txt-repairltpathgt...))</sup> knows how to repair the two-way links between the repository and a worktree as long as a link in one or the other direction is sound.
>
> For instance, if a linked worktree is moved (without using [`git worktree move`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/cf76baea41bb7f6431dbfa5744c861fdb844d20b/Documentation/git-worktree.txt#L111)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree#Documentation/git-worktree.txt-move))</sup>), repair is possible because the worktree still knows the location of the repository even though the repository no longer knows where the worktree is.
> Similarly, if the repository is moved, repair is possible since the repository still knows the locations of the worktrees even though the worktrees no longer know where the repository is.
>
> However, if both the repository and the worktrees are moved, then links are severed in both directions, and no repair is possible.
> This is the case even when the new worktree locations are specified as arguments to `git worktree repair`.
>
> The reason for this limitation is twofold.
>
> - First, when `repair` consults the worktree's `gitfile` (`/path/to/worktree/.git`) to determine the corresponding `<repo>/worktrees/<id>/gitdir` file to fix, `<repo>` is the old path to the repository, thus it is unable to fix the `gitdir` file at its new location since it doesn't know where it is.
> - Second, when `repair` consults `<repo>/worktrees/<id>/gitdir` to find the location of the worktree's `gitfile` (`/path/to/worktree/.git`), the path recorded in `gitdir` is the old location of the worktree's `gitfile`, thus it is unable to repair the `gitfile` since it doesn't know where it is.
>
> Fix these shortcomings by teaching `repair` to attempt to infer the new location of the `<repo>/worktrees/<id>/gitdir` file when the location recorded in the worktree's `gitfile` has become stale but the file is otherwise well-formed.
>
> The inference is intentionally simple-minded.
> For each worktree path specified as an argument, `git worktree repair` manually reads the "`.git`" `gitfile` at that location and, if it is well-formed, extracts the `<id>`.
> It then searches for a corresponding `<id>` in `<repo>/worktrees/` and, if found, concludes that there is a reasonable match and updates `<repo>/worktrees/<id>/gitdir` to point at the specified worktree path.
> In order for `<repo>` to be known, `git worktree repair` must be run in the main worktree or bare repository.
>
> `git worktree repair` first attempts to repair each incoming `/path/to/worktree/.git` `gitfile` to point at the repository, and then attempts to repair outgoing `<repo>/worktrees/<id>/gitdir` files to point at the worktrees.
>
> This sequence was chosen arbitrarily when originally implemented since the order of fixes is immaterial as long as one side of the two-way link between the repository and a worktree is sound.
>
> However, for this new repair technique to work, the order must be reversed.   This is because the new inference mechanism, when it is successful, allows the outgoing `<repo>/worktrees/<id>/gitdir` file to be repaired, thus fixing one side of the two-way link.
> Once that side is fixed, the other side can be fixed by the existing repair mechanism, hence the order of repairs is now significant.
>
> Two safeguards are employed to avoid hijacking a worktree from a different repository if the user accidentally specifies a foreign worktree as an argument.
>
> - The first, as described above, is that it requires an `<id>` match between the repository and the worktree. That itself is not foolproof for preventing hijack, so:
> - the second safeguard is that the inference will only kick in if the worktree's `/path/to/worktree/.git` `gitfile` does not point at a repository.

`git worktree` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/cf76baea41bb7f6431dbfa5744c861fdb844d20b/Documentation/git-worktree.txt#L146-L150):

> If both the main working tree and linked working trees have been moved
> manually, then running `repair` in the main working tree and specifying the
> new `<path>` of each linked working tree will reestablish all connections
> in both directions.